# Unable to create converter for my class in Android Retrofit

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I am trying to develop clent-server application with Retrofit. My application sends to server json with a string "image" and responses a json with a string with field "name".

My API:

```
public interface API {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/classification/imagenet")
    Call<GestureJson> getName(@Body ImageJson json);
}
```

ImageJson:

```
public class ImageJson {
    public String imageString;
}
```

NameJson:

```
public class NameJson {
    public int gestureNumber;
}
```

When user pressed on button in Main Activity MyVoid is called (url is already known):

```
public void MyVoid() {
        String requestUrl = url;
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(requestUrl)
                .build();
        API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
        ImageJson json = new ImageJson();
        json.imageString = image_uri.toString();
        Call<GestureJson> call = api.getName(json);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<GestureJson>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GestureJson> call, Response<GestureJson> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    status = RESPONSE_SUCCESS;
                } else {
                    status = RESPONSE_FAIL;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GestureJson> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

I have three problems:

1) I don't know what's the difference between Retrofit and Retrofit2. What is better to use?

2) .addCallAdapterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) underlined how wrong (in Retorfit and Retrofit2).

3) I can compile application if i delete .addCallAdapterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()). But I have a problem:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.opencvproject, PID: 17742
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.example.opencvproject.GestureJson
    for method API.getGesture
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Retrofit2 is better because Retrofit outdated (last release was on 2014 https://github.com/square/retrofit/releases/tag/parent-1.6.0). Number 2 in name is just a library version.
2. GsonConverterFactory may be underlined because you did't add dependency `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson`
3. If you delete `addCallAdapterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` then Retrofit would't know how to deserialize json to objects. GsonConverterFactory use Gson libarary (https://github.com/google/gson) under the hood to deserialize server json responses.

Comment: Right dependency is `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'`

Comment: 2.9.0 is a last version for retrofit2 and 2.0.2 is a last version for converter-gson. So should I use reftrofit2 version 2.0.2 and converter-gson version 2.0.2?

Comment: There is a 2.9.0 version of gson-converter https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/converter-gson/2.9.0. gson-converter  version should be the same as retrofit version. You can also use older version of library if you want